# Query to find last N events Type "2" occurred immediately before events Type "1"

Tags: sql, date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a long list of events (millions) sent from different machines.

I need to obtain last N events of type "2" occurred before events type "1" in the same machine

I found a solution for N=1 but  **I'm not able to find a solution fon N events**

This is my solution for N=1:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CodeEvent] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Mach] [varchar](max) NULL
) 

INSERT @T VALUES
(2,'12:35:28','M2'),
(1,'12:35:21','M3'),
(4,'12:34:54','M3'),
(8,'12:34:35','M2'),
(2,'12:33:28','M2'),
(2,'12:33:21','M3'),
(1,'12:32:54','M1'),
(8,'12:32:35','M2'),
(1,'12:32:28','M2'),
(2,'12:32:25','M1'),
(1,'12:32:23','M3'),
(3,'12:32:21','M2'),
(2,'12:31:28','M2'),
(2,'12:31:21','M1'),
(4,'12:30:54','M3'),
(8,'12:30:35','M2'),
(1,'12:30:28','M2'),
(2,'12:30:25','M1'),
(2,'12:30:23','M3'),
(2,'12:30:21','M2'),
(1,'12:30:20','M3')

SELECT * FROM @T ORDER BY DateTime Desc;

WITH 
---- T1 All Events
T1 AS (SELECT TOP 100 * 
       FROM @T
       ORDER BY DateTime desc) 
,

---- T2 Events '1'
T2 AS (SELECT TOP 100 * 
       FROM T1 AS T
       WHERE (T.[CodeEvent] = 1)
       ORDER BY DateTime desc ) 
,

---- T4 Last Events type '2' Before type '1' same Mach
T4 AS   
    (select 
    T.ID,
    T.DateTime,
    T.[CodeEvent],
    T.[Mach],
    (SELECT  Top 1 T1.ID
        FROM T1 
        WHERE ((T1.Datetime < T.Datetime) 
           AND (T1.[Mach]=T.[Mach])
           AND (T1.CodeEvent=2))
        ORDER BY T1.DateTime desc) AS LAST_EVENT_ID
    FROM T2 AS T)
,
    
--- T6 get Event from ID
T6 AS (SELECT  
       T.[ID]
      ,T.[CodeEvent]
      ,T.[DateTime]
      ,T.[Mach]
       FROM T4 JOIN T1 AS T
       ON (T4.LAST_EVENT_ID = T.ID)) 


SELECT * FROM T2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T6
ORDER BY [Mach],DateTime Desc
```

This is what I obtain for N=1

```
1   1900-01-01 12:32:54.0000000 M1
2   1900-01-01 12:32:25.0000000 M1

1   1900-01-01 12:32:28.0000000 M2
2   1900-01-01 12:31:28.0000000 M2

1   1900-01-01 12:30:28.0000000 M2
2   1900-01-01 12:30:21.0000000 M2

1   1900-01-01 12:35:21.0000000 M3
2   1900-01-01 12:33:21.0000000 M3

1   1900-01-01 12:32:23.0000000 M3
2   1900-01-01 12:30:23.0000000 M3
```

This is what I would like to obtain for N=2

```
1   1900-01-01 12:32:54.0000000 M1
2   1900-01-01 12:32:25.0000000 M1
2   1900-01-01 12:31:21.0000000 M1

1   1900-01-01 12:32:28.0000000 M2
2   1900-01-01 12:31:28.0000000 M2
2   1900-01-01 12:30:33.0000000 M2

1   1900-01-01 12:35:21.0000000 M3
2   1900-01-01 12:33:21.0000000 M3
2   1900-01-01 12:30:23.0000000 M3
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: oracle, sql-server, postgresql...?

Answer (score 1):

I understand as a gaps-and-islands problem. For each machine, you want to retain all "1" events and *N* preceding "2" events.

An approach is to define groups with a window sum that increments for every "1" event. You can then enumerate records within the groups with `row_number()`, and filter.

This answers the question for N = 2.

```
select CodeEvent, DateTime, Mech
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by Mach, grp order by DateTime desc) rn
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            sum(case when CodeEvent = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by Mach order by DateTime desc) grp
        from @T t
        where CodeEvent in (1, 2)   
    ) t
) t
where rn <= 3
order by DateTime
```

You control N by adjusting the final filter on `rn`.